# Display html file inside iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

How to display a HTML file from my system in iframe using rails?

I will explain my issue...

I have a view file that has an iframe which calls an action through `<iframe src="controller/action?param=somevalue"></iframe>` and the action renders a HTML file based on the params.

The HTML file called has reference to stylesheets and javascripts in the format `<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/About.js"></script>`

When viewed in browser the HTML file displays correctly with the styles and javascript but when viewed in the application the styling and scripts are not working from the external file. On viewing the source code for the external files i get "Unknown action" error.

What is that i am doing wrong in this?

Comment: Just specifying the file path in the src attribute of the iframe doesn't work? Like /public/static/myHtmlPage.html

Comment: when i specify the file path, it doesn't include the css and js files referred by the html

Comment: I found the mistake i made. Its because of routes being not defined properly. When i give relative urls in the html file, the rails views assumes the full path to be some thing like src="controller/common/About.js". As there is no action defined by the mane common i was getting the Unknown action error. I have redefined my routes and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake I made. Its because of routes being not defined properly. When I give relative urls in the html file, the rails views assumes the full path to be some thing like src="controller/common/About.js". As there is no action defined by the name common I was getting the Unknown action error. I have redefined my routes and its working fine now.

Comment: I found my issue and corrected that. As i don't want to receive any responses for this question i am marking this as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

(reacting to yr last comment): you need to specify css and js files in the iframed html page separately.  html in an iframe is rendered completely independent from the surrounding page.

This is not a rails-related question imho.